# Node Entity needs to be found again after adding relationships (neo4j/java/spring)

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I've used the @NodeEntity annotation for a class topic. In Topic there is the following: (For sake of brevity, I've narrowed the error down, so I'm only writing up the relevant parts of the code.)

```
public class Topic {

    ...

    @RelatedTo(type = "MADE_OF", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    public Set<Topic> madeOf;

    @RelatedTo(type = "MADE_OF", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    public Set<Topic> partOf;

}
```

Now, this gets instantiated elsewhere like:

```
    Topic myTopic = new Topic();
    madeOf.addAll(some list of topics with empty partOf already in the graph);
    myTopic = template.save(myTopic());
```

Now, if I check over the set of topics in myTopic.madeOf, all of them are empty, even though they should all include myTopic. Alternatively, if I do:

```
    Topic myTopic = new Topic();
    madeOf.addAll(some list of topics with empty partOf already in the graph);
    myTopic = template.save(myTopic());
    myTopic = template.findOne(myTopic());
```

and now check the same thing, everything is as it should be. Obviously finding this entity over and over slows down my code considerably. The same behavior occurs even if I add the relationships to the Neo4JTemplate explicitly with template.createRelationshipBetween(...).

Any ideas?

Comment: I assume "template.save(myTopic())" is a typo and you meant "template.save(myTopic)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you do a `template.save` you can do a `template.fetch(myTopic.getMadeOf())` to fetch all related topics in one shot and then use the *myTopic* in usual way

Comment: That works right, thanks a ton. Is there a way to make this any cleaner? I'm used to scientific computation and usually build standalone command-line stuff, so I'm a bit new to all this annotation business.

Comment: @MichaelJarretBaume are you talking about my or Gopi's answer?

Comment: @tstorms Gopi. Lazy loading inside of each Topic is less than ideal given my current setup. I still thought that there was a way to keep this working with annotation, though.

Comment: @Gopi, there is, see my answer?

Comment: I would generally not use @ Fetch, to avoid fetching everything all the time. Another thing is, in these kind of cases if you use @ Fetch, you have to be very careful about implementing toString() and similar methods or if you are trying to convert the object to some format such as json using some libraries, as it can very easily lead to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

By default with simple mapping enabled, all relationships are lazily fetched. If you want them to be eagerly loaded, use [@Fetch](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/api/) on your relationships (thus madeOf and partOf).

```
@Fetch
@RelatedTo(type = "MADE_OF", direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
public Set<Topic> madeOf;
```